# ServiceStack Ormlite using Select with NoLock

Tags: servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

I have the following simple OrmLite select statement:

```
SpiderUser lSpiderUser = db.Select<SpiderUser>(
    su => su.WindowsUserName == vWindowsUserName).SingleOrDefault();
```

(The variable 'db' is of type IDbConnection).

I would like this query to run using NoLock.  Ormlite from version 5.7 has 'SqlServerTableHint.NoLock', but I do not understand how to include this hint in the above query.

Please help...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[OrmLite's SqlServerTableHint](https://docs.servicestack.net/ormlite/sql-server-features.html#sql-server-table-hints) are only for table joins.

You can customize the generated SQL using a Typed SqlExpression, e.g:

```cs
var q = db.From<SpiderUser>()
    .Where(su => su.WindowsUserName == vWindowsUserName)
    .WithSqlFilter(sql => $"{sql} WITH (NOLOCK)");

var lSpiderUser = db.Single(q);
```

Comment: Thanks, I have done what you suggest previously.

But since OrmLite has made 'SqlServerTableHint.NoLock', I would assume using 'SqlServerTableHint.NoLock' would be the recommended way?

Also, it would result in shorter/cleaner code.

Comment: @BjørnSigurdBenestadJohansen It's a modifier for table join expressions.

Comment: Ok, so that's why I only found SqlServerTableHint.NoLock examples including join expressions... ;)
Thanks for answer.